# How to tag names on google photos?

Tags: google-plus, google-photos

I have downloaded the google photos. And I've uploaded more than 6,000 personal photos. But I find it hard to tag person names?
Where can I tag persons' names so that I can search them?
I've seen the google I/O and the speaker show that Google-Photos can recognize his daughter. But I can't even tag nor search a person's name.

However I know that I can upload photos to Google+ so that I can tag them. But it sounds crazy to share all my 6000+ photos to Google Plus.

What should I to to reach the same effect on the Google I/O.(Make all my photos searchable?)

Comment: that feature uses image recognition to detect faces and categorize them automatically. no need to tag.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I got it.
The only reason is that face detecting is not available out side the US.(I am from China)
To solve this,just use VPN the first time you start the APP.
(On Android clear app data & On iOS re-install it)

Comment: I haven't been able to upload new photos since using the 'vpn trick' to enable face recognition outside the US. Not sure if anyone else is having the same problem though.